# Parameters error in mysql.connector for python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

An error regarding SQL just appeared in my program while I didn't change the code at all, and it was working before. Here is a snippet of code that gives error. To give some context, it is a raspberry pi system that records attendance with help of RFID chips.

```
...
if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
      lcd.clear()
      lcd.message("Overwrite\nexisting user?")
      overwrite = input("Overwite (Y/N)? ")
      if overwrite[0] == 'Y' or overwrite[0] == 'y':
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message("Overwriting user.")
        time.sleep(1)
        sql_insert = "UPDATE users SET name, room = %s WHERE rfid_uid=%s"
      else:
        continue;
else:
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (name, room, rfid_uid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
lcd.clear()
        
lcd.message('Enter new name')
new_name = input("Name: ")
lcd.clear()
        
lcd.message('Enter room number')
new_room = input("Room: ")
lcd.clear()

####this line below gives error
cursor.execute(sql_insert, (new_name, new_room, id))

db.commit()
...
```

Here is an error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/checkinsystem/ra.py", line 67, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_insert, (new_name, new_room, id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 561, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

I've tried some slight syntax changes but given that it was working perfectly before, I'm clueless at this point.
Any suggestions on how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think i had the same problem with you before. try this

```
else:
    n = input('Enter new name')
    lcd.clear()
    r = input('Enter room number')
    lcd.clear()
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (name, room, rfid_uid) VALUES ("+n+","+r+","+rfid_uid+")"
    lcd.clear()
    cursor.execute(sql_insert)
    db.commmit()
```

i really hope this helps or maybe needed little adjustments.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should sanitize the inputs before inserting them into the SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not what was causing the problem. I should've included a broader picture of my code in the question as the problem was in the UPDATE query which I did not consider. It was just incorrect SQL syntax, should've been
sql_insert = "UPDATE users SET name = %s, room = %s WHERE rfid_uid=%s" instead of what I have in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Error in SQL syntax. Should be `sql_insert = "UPDATE users SET name = %s, room = %s WHERE rfid_uid=%s"` instead of `sql_insert = "UPDATE users SET name, room = %s WHERE rfid_uid=%s"`